# Angular 7 - Can you call a 'local' method inside subscription?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

The code below stops working if I change the order of `this.item` re-assignments and put the line with `convertToArray()` method above the other two:

```
combineLatest(params, queryParams, (params, qparams) => ({ params, qparams }))
      .subscribe(allParams => {
        this.item.color = allParams.qparams['color'] || allParams.params['color'] || ''; //this line must be above
        this.item.price = parseInt(allParams.qparams['price']) || 0; //this line also
        this.items.features = this.convertToArray(allParams.qparams['features']);
      });
```

The `convertToArray` method just converts a string to an array (`if (typeof(a) === string) { return [a] }` ) and works perfectly if it's put on the last line of subscribtion. If it's not, all that follows doesn't get executed and I'd like to understand why.

Comment: Is this.items.features defined? What happens on else? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: There are no errors in the console, I discovered this bug after a long time of searching, when I console.log all 3 lines and saw that the ones after this `convertToArray` method are not printing. This.items.features is defined as an empty array beforehand. On `else` an empty array is returned.

Comment: You seem to have a `)` to much at the end of every line in `subscribe`. What's up with that?